# QGIS 'Packing Problem'?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, vector-grid

I have 45 irregular polygons (geographic areas) of various sizes. I need to grid each one into a universal number of same-sized squares/rectangles (same sized within each polygon, not necessarily across all 45 polygons). Presently I’m having to create a grid over the polygon’s base layer using near-random spacings (horizontal and vertical), then clip it to the layer’s boundary and count the remaining squares. Then to repeat with different spacings until I end up at my target number. After just six polygons, I’ve lost my mind.

Is there a way (some preset or code) to automate this, perhaps by calculating the H & V spacings based on the target number of squares/rectangles required? Is this in fact a true ‘packing problem’?

I’ve tried with WG84/Pseudo-Mercator EPSG:3857 and the projected OSGB36/BNG EPSG:27700 coordinate reference systems. I’m using QGIS Desktop 3.28.2-Firenze on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, 64-bit Jammy Jellyfish.

Example output:
[image]

Comment: What is your "target number"?

Comment: Also, do the rectangles need to be fully within the features? Do they need to be oriented to the north, or may they be rotated?

Comment: It would be helpful to add a picture of what you have and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you both. Sample output added as requested. The squares/rectangles are always north-south oriented. :)

Comment: Web Mercator is not the right projection for binning things so far north.